# Getting same prediction for all the classes in mobilenetV2 - Tensorflow

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am using mobile net v2 for multiclass image classification problem,

**here is how I am loading the data**

```
train_datagen=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.1
    )


test_datagen=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
     rescale=1./255,
     validation_split=0.1
) 


train_datagen=train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    dataset_dir,
    target_size=(image_size,image_size),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    subset='training'
)

test_datagen=test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    dataset_dir,
    target_size=(image_size,image_size),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    subset='validation'
)
```

**This is my model:**

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(image_size, image_size, 3))
base_model = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(weights="imagenet", input_shape=(image_size, image_size, 3), include_top=False)
base_model.trainable = False

base_learning_rate = 0.0001

flatten_layer = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()

drop_out = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)

output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, activation= 'softmax') 


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  base_model,
  flatten_layer,
  drop_out,
  output
])

model.compile(optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=base_learning_rate/10),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

EPOCHS = 10

history = model.fit(train_datagen, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1, validation_data=test_datagen)
```

[image]

[image]

So finally i am getting validation accuracy of 87% which is not best but not worst also

**here is how i check the outcomes of the model, The code :**

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np

test_path = r"F:\Study\PGDAIML\Project-10\Latest_data_set\NewDataSet-Cropped-B&W -Light -Test"

test_classes = os.listdir(test_path)


actual_class_level = []
predicted_class_level = []

def prdict_classlable(image_path):
    
    image_pred = image.load_img(image_path,target_size=(224,224))
    image_pred = image.img_to_array(image_pred)
    image_pred = np.expand_dims(image_pred,axis=0)
    
    return classes_name[np.argmax(model.predict(image_pred))]


for eachlass in test_classes:

    class_path = os.path.join(test_path,eachlass)
    samples_perclass = os.listdir(class_path)
    
    for each_sample in samples_perclass:
        sample_file_path = os.path.join(class_path,each_sample)
        
        actual_class_level.append(eachlass)
        predicted_class_level.append(prdict_classlable(sample_file_path))
```

**Here is how to plot confusion matrix:**

```
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
    
cm = confusion_matrix(actual_class_level, predicted_class_level)

disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm, display_labels=class_names)


print(cm)
#fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,17))

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (30, 10)

disp.plot(cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

print(type(plt))

plt.show()
```

**Here is the confusion matrix :**

[image]
here I have a point, I have also made a simple baseline model, there with almost similar accuracy I get a good result almost all of the class gets precited properly, in case of mobilenetV2 I am facing this issue, what am I missing?